# Unable to build the signed APK from flutter module integrated Native Android Project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

With the Flutter module integrated into the native Android project, I am attempting to build the signed APK, but I am encountering the error that is listed below. Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue?

'''A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':flutter:debugApi' after it has been included in dependency resolution.
> '''